# Kinesis stream to AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I am currently using DynamoDB streams and looking forward to move to Kinesis streams as I want to gain control over the number of records I like to process from the streams.

I have been reading about Kinesis streams and lambda. There are many articles about Kinesis streams and EC2's where multiple consumers and KCL etc..

All I would like to know is, If I go with lambda for Kinesis stream, what is the expected behavior?

- Like Dynamo streams, when Kinesis has records in the streams, lambda gets triggered with the bunch of records in the event?
- Whenever there are records in Kinesis stream, Lambda gets triggered and Lambda can go ahead and read the shards to fetch the records and process further.

I am looking for the second option in the above. I do not want the lambda to be triggered with set of records but I want to control the amount I read.

Could anyone explain how can I gain control of Kinesis streams in Lambda?

Comment: Here's [a sample repository](https://github.com/gnokoheat/aws-serverless-data-pipeline-by-terraform) made by terraform.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe a lambda to a Kinesis stream. When you subscribe you can specify the batch size, 1 to 1000 as I recall.
The lambda will be invoked for each shard in the stream when there are records available up to the batch size. If the lambda errors, (e.g. returns an error or times out) it will be retried with the same data. It will be retried until it succeeds or the records age out of the stream.
The lambda will be invoked around once per second per shard if there are records available. The lambda is invoked with whatever records are available up to the batch size.

There will be only one concurrent lambda invocation per shard. This is to guarantee the ordering of records inside a shard.

Generally the behavior for Kinesis streams is the same as for DynamoDB streams.

Comment: Lets say if you set the batch size as 500. Does it wait to trigger till there are 500 records?

Comment: Also you mean to say, you cannot control the Kinesis stream from Lambda? but its the other way around?

Comment: Does DynamoDB streams also does the same thing with lambda like you explained above for Kinesis streams?

Comment: Edited to answer two of your questions, but I'm not sure what you are asking regarding Kinesis stream controlling lambda or the reverse.

Comment: Sorry. Let me explain. I want the trigger for Lambda when there are records available in the stream..  I would like to read the records directly from the stream but not from the event. Is it possible?

Comment: I suppose you could connect a lambda to the kinesis, then when it triggers ignore the event and use the Kinesis SDK to read from the Kinesis stream. You would have to keep track of the iterator id and stuff. Perhaps you could explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: The problem I am facing is
* From dynamoDB streams, I have set batchSize as 1k. But I never got more than 5 records in one event. 
* Due to this reason, There are more concurrent lambda executions happening. 
*There is a huge lag for the dynamoDB records to hit lambda from streams and i am trying to figure out why. One reason could be the above concurrency executions.
* I am not sure what else to look at. 
* As in our current event through dynamo streams, We are not getting huge batch of records in one event, So I am exploring Kinesis so that I can poll the records in batches as required

Comment: With EC2 in place we can poll kinesis streams as required.
But with Lambda.. Like you said if I try to ignore the event, and if I do the polling of my own.. do you think those event records will be available to read while polling? Because may be Kinesis already polled them?

Comment: If dynamoDB streams also concurrently triggers lambda based on number of shards available... then I do not see any reason to go for Kinesis streams.. Jus that Kinesis is independent (not tied specific to DynamoDB)

Comment: In my experience the DynamoDB streams to Lambda integration is much faster than Kinesis to lambda. How large is your table (items and size) and how many concurrent invocations are you getting? DynamoDB will invoke one lambda per partition (as I understand it), so your concurrency will depend on the number of partitions.

Comment: Then thats too huge.. Our paritition key is UUID. So that many number of lambda invocations.

Comment: Any suggestions on what could be done to reduce the lag I am facing with the streams to lambda?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195717/discussion-between-cementblocks-and-deepak).